# How to stop infinite vertical drag in google map javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map javascript sdk for showing map and data on the map.

I have done a lot of google search but couldn't find solution for stopping vertial drag when the map is over.

When I try to zoom out and hold & drag the map vertically, It keeps going even after the map is finished and a grey blank screen starts appearing.

Here's the screencast of the issue: http://recordit.co/DTZc9xyR4m

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Map</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initMap() {
            Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 3,
                center: {lat: 12.9716, lng: 77.5946},
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                minZoom: 2,
                maxZoom: 18
            });

            Map.addListener('idle', function(){
                console.log(Map.getBounds().toJSON());
            });

            console.log('Map initialized!');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in the mapSettings when initializing the google map:

```
  restriction: {
    latLngBounds: { north: 85, south: -85, west: -179.999, east: 179.999 },
    strictBounds: true,
  },
```